# How to import npm module into a Polymer 2.0 element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, requirejs, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to understand if what I am doing is even possible within the realms of Polymer. My current example involves trying to import an npm module called currency-formatter into a Polymer 2.0 element that can be called.

The problem I run into is that although I can import requirejs to find the npm module, I can't seem to be able to run the module without it giving me the following error:

> require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Module name "currency-formatter" has
>   not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Take this code for example:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<script src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>

<dom-module id="currency-display">
  <template>
        <style>
          :host {
              display: inline-block;
          }
        </style>
    <input type="text" value={{currency::input}}></input>
    <p>Currency: - {{formatCurrency}}</p>
  </template>

  <script>
    class CurrencyDisplay extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'currency-display'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          currency: {
            type: String,
            value: 0,
          },
          formatCurrency: {
            type: String,
            notify: true,
            computed: '_getCurrency(currency)'
          },
          type: {
            type: String,
            value: 'USD',
          }
        };
      }

      _getCurrency (currency) {
        var currencyFormatter = require('currency-formatter');
        var formattedCurrency = currencyFormatter.format(parseInt(currency), { code: type });

        return formattedCurrency;
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(CurrencyDisplay.is, CurrencyDisplay);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: did you check callback style of `require`? `var moduleName = 'foo';
require([moduleName], function(fooModule){
    // do something with fooModule
})`

Comment: I have, but effectively when I do a call onto the module name it fails and says no module found on path, when I direct it to the path it should be, it gives this new error:
`Module name "accounting" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

Comment: Any updates with this? I'm also stuck on the same boat.

Comment: Have you tried <script type="module" src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>